# Inputting date in custom format Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm struggling with the custom date in Google Sheets.

I would like to set a custom date format that goes day/month/year instead of the default month/day/year.

If I setup this format for my cell in the "custom date" menu and then enter a date (day/month/year) in my cell it switches it around to month/day/year. It seems to force me to enter it first in the default month/day/year order and then it will display in the format that I want.

How can I setup up so I'm also allowed to input the date in day/month/year not just display it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have that date format by default you need to act on the locale settings.
For example look at the Italian settings:

[image]

... and the result of

```
=now()
```

[image]

After changing the setting, each date entered will have the format you requested and can be **visually** changed with the application's custom formats.